# can we set primary key in core data

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I am making a application in which i use core data .
Now in this i need to create a primary key same as we create in sqlite (auto increment type ).
Is this possible with core data .If yes then how any link or suggestion so as how to proceed for the same.

Regards
Mrugen

Comment: possible duplication of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901640/core-data-primary-key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since core data is a persistance framework more than a general purpose database, it abstracts the primary key.

Answer (score 4):

CoreData isn't a Database rather **its an Object Relational Mapping Solution**. It's an object persistence layer. There is no concept of primary keys or foreign keys in CoreData.

If you want to establish a relationship between two entities. You'll define a relationship, CoreData takes care of how that relationship is stored.

[image]

Select an entity, use plus button at the bottom of the entities attributes list, select add relationship, select the destination entity from the dropdown.

Select the destination entity and define an inverse relationship in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is NO.
To achieve similar thing, 
You can have an 'id' field in the table, before inserting into the table get the maximum value of the 'id' and then add 1 to the value.

With a filed 'userID' in the table ENTITY_USER (users), the get the highest user ID.

```
+ (NSInteger) getMaxUserID
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *res = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:ENTITY_USER
                                           inManagedObjectContext:[DataBaseManager sharedInstance].managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:res];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"userID" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    [request setFetchLimit:1];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [[DataBaseManager sharedInstance].managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    [request release];
    if (results == nil) {
        NSLog(@"error fetching the results: %@",error);
    }

    NSInteger maximumValue = 0;
    if (results.count == 1) {
        CDUser *result = (CDUser *)[results objectAtIndex:0];
        maximumValue =  [result.userID integerValue];
    }
    return maximumValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just use the objectID property of NSManagedObject? This would give you a unique reference to your object.