# How do I set the 'relatedbyattribute' for a Core Data attribute

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios7, magicalrecord

I have a Core Data store, managed by MagicalRecord;  one of the attributes is the primary key, but I can't seem to find any docs on how to set it as such (many places talk about the **relatedbyattribute**, but none say how to set it.

Do I do it programmatically or in XCode (IB)?  or?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the "Indexed" checkbox in the model editor.

[image]

While this does not ensure uniqueness, it will speed up the lookup. You will have to check for unique values yourself, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/903778/427083).

Comment: Ahhh... right in front of me! :D  And will this *automatically* reject an add of a record with the same value for that attribute?

Comment: Not sure, try it out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look for the User Info area of the attri ute properties inspector. From there, you can enter the relatedBy key and the primary value.