# How can I get the value of the primary key of an NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

I found out that Core Data is basically an SQLite database. Each entity is a separate table. There are also tables which are not entities, including `Z_METADATA`, `Z_MODELCACHE` and `Z_PRIMARYKEY`. I don't know what they do.

Anyway, I saw that the fields of the "entity tables" is roughly the same as those properties I added in the data model, plus a few extras. For example, if my entity has only one property called `date`. The table will have a `ZDATE` field as well as `Z_PK`, `Z_ENT`, and `Z_OPT`.

So apparently, each entity has a primary key that is stored in the `Z_PK` field! I want to get the value of this primary key of a specific `NSManagedObject`. And I want to query the database for an `NSManagedObject` that has a specific primary key.

So basically, something like this:

```
let pk = myManagedObject.primaryKey
// the below should return myManagedObject
managedObjContext.objectWithPrimaryKey(someEntityDescription, pk)
```

I searched the docs for `NSManagedObject` and saw an `objectID`. But I don't think this is it, or is it?

Comment: I believe you are referring to Object ID when you say primary key..check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901640/core-data-primary-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data does not support doing this, because Core Data's API is very different from SQL. If you think in terms of SQL, you're going to make Core Data much more difficult than it needs to be.

The approximate Core Data equivalent of your code snippet would be something like (using Swift 3 syntax):

```
let objectID = myManagedObject.objectID

// Later
let myManagedObject = context.object(with: objectID)
// Or...
let myManagedObject = context.existingObject(with: objectID)
```

Using `object(with:)` is faster but potentially less safe. Using `existingObject(with:)` may be slightly slower but is safer.