# How to get the Core data Primary key value in ios Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to access the Primary Key in a table using Core Data.
Does anyone know how to fetch the Primary Key Value from a table?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AnupamMishra's answer is right, but to uniquely identify record you should use `objectID` property.

Answer (score 5):

Core Data is not a database; it is an object persistence framework. If you want to use a primary key, you should use an unique id_object attribute in your entity.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that Core Data is an `object-graph persistence framework`, not a `database`. Things like primary keys are abstracted away because they depend on the implementation of the persistent store. [More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901640/core-data-primary-key)

Comment: This looks like a verbatim copy of http://stackoverflow.com/a/901767/1187415, without attribution. If you think that a question has been answered before then you can flag it as a duplicate, there is no need to repeat identical answers. – You can quote from another answer (with a link to the original source), but that makes only sense if you add more information.